# Who is Paul Graham's father?

Tags: mathematicians

In one of his essays, [Y Combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_Combinator) (YC) co-founder [Paul Graham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Graham_(programmer)) (PG) wrote$^\color{magenta}{\star}$ the following.

> My father is a mathematician. For most of my childhood he worked for Westinghouse, modelling nuclear reactors [...] He grew up in the small Welsh seacoast town of Pwllheli.

Who would that mathematician be?

I suspect it's [Ronald Graham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Graham), but he was born in the US, not the UK. Also, it seems he didn't work on nuclear reactors.

---

<sub>$\color{magenta}{\star}$ Paul Graham, [What doesn't seem like work?](http://www.paulgraham.com/work.html), January 2015.</sub>

Comment: The [MacTutor entry on Ronald Graham](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Graham/) states that his two children were named Cheryl and Mark.

Comment: A mathematician working for Westinghouse perhaps did not publish any research.  In that case, we would likely not have heard of him.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar why did a mathematician working for Westinghouse perhaps not publish any research?

Comment: @Ooker ... My conjecture is just statistical. Many mathematicians do "real" work rather than academics.  A few industrial mathematicians do also publish, but most do not.

Comment: ah do you mean not publish in math journals? What do you mean by "real" work?

Comment: There is also this [tweet](https://twitter.com/paulg/status/1281489311259602945)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo my intention of introducing a little about Paul Graham is to prove the significance of the answer, but your edit is fine as well. I haven't thought about posting on HN, will try ;)

Comment: @Ooker Yes, but "YC co-founder" should be enough.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo why do you delete your comment about posting on HN?

Comment: @Ooker You have already read it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was John Graham (1933-2017). As Paul says, "*for most of my childhood he worked for Westinghouse, modelling nuclear reactors*", and he remained in the nuclear industry for the rest of his life. His B.S. in mathematics was from the University of Wales, and he did graduate work at the University of Illinois and the University of London. Here is his short bio from the [obituary](https://cdn.ans.org/about/presidents/docs/john-graham-bio.pdf):

> "*He was been engaged in nuclear safety for 60 years, including ongoing work with the Pacific Nuclear Council on promotion of peaceful uses of nuclear technologies, since 1997. Graham began a career with Westinghouse in 1969 as Manager of Nuclear Safety at Westinghouse Advanced Reactors Division, Madison, Wisc., with responsibility for safety of the Clinch River Breeder Reactor in Tennessee, among other projects. In 1985, he became the Licensing Manager for the Basalt Waster Isolation Project.*

> *After he left Westinghouse, he was named the Director of Nuclear Safety for Atomic Energy of Canada Limited (AECL) until 1992, when he became vice-president of British Nuclear Fuels (BNFL). He also worked for the U.K. Atomic Energy Agency as a senior scientist and for the Atomic Energy of Canada Research for British Nuclear Fuels as a Director of Safety. He was a recognized Fellow at Westinghouse... He wrote [Fast Reactor Safety](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fast_Reactor_Safety/y0jXPlC7X18C?hl=en&gbpv=0) in 1971 and authored 25 other books.*"

Nuclear News ran his [extended profile](https://www.ans.org/file/532/john-graham-nn-article.pdf) when he was the American Nuclear Society president in 1995-96. He was born in Wales, went to college in the US, then returned to England to work in Harwell labs until 1968, when he got a job at Westinghouse ("*Claire had good reason to be upset, Graham concedes. They had two small children at that time - Paul, aged four, and Jennifer, who was less than a year old*"). They settled at the US and eventually became American citizens. There is a bit on his engagement with mathematics:

> "*Mathematics was something I've always liked- I love numbers; they're fascinating. I liked algebra. and I love calculus. I truly believe the whole of life is based on calculus and any aberrations in life are simply aberrations in the calculus... I applied to various places and was accepted at the universities
> of Ohio and Illinois, and went to the University
> of Illinois in 1954-55. I studied quantum
> mechanics and mathematics. I didn't stay to
> get the master's degree because I didn't think
> the master's was at all significant, and besides,
> I wanted to take some time to travel around the
> States.*

> *I found out
> that everybody in that graduate department
> was working on similar problems with
> slightly different force fields. So I was doing
> neutron-deuteron impact problems with a given
> force field. Someone next to me was working
> with a different force field, and someone
> else was doing deuteron-deuteron problems
> with my force field. We were all contributing
> to the professor's thesis, but we were each only
> a very small brick in his edifice. That's not
> very satisfying. So I didn't finish that degree...*"

However, it does not seem like he did much mathematical work after the early years, aside from nuclear modeling (MathSciNet lists no publications by him). His profile also has a childhood picture of Paul and Jennifer, his kids, and a picture of him, his wife Claire and Paul, age 30, with a short blurb:

> "*Today, John and Claire live in Golden,
> Colo. Claire works in the controller's office
> for the American Animal Hospital Association
> (you are not allowed to call it Aaha!).
> Their son Paul, now age 30, has a doctorate in
> computer science, but is currently working as
> an artist and as CEO of ARTIX, a World Wide
> Web company.*

Comment: How did you identify him? Does he have any kinship with Ronald Graham?

Comment: @Ooker Working from Paul's remarks about Westinghouse and nuclear safety, John was well known in that area. His profile confirmed that he was the father. No relation to Ronald, he was a natural born American and the name is pretty common on both sides of the pond.

Comment: so you just suspect him right after reading Paul's description?

Comment: @Ooker No, I did not know of him before. I searched for mathematicians involved with nuclear safety who worked in Westinghouse. His name and bio came up because he was a prominent figure, so I checked.